# Step through code in AngularJS - controller

Tags: angularjs

https://plnkr.co/edit/mBiv4r3JoHxKtDtRR2qM?p=preview

```
var myApp=angular.module('my',[]);
```

Above is the code. Can someone please explain the flow of the statements such that why in the console line 12 gets executed before line 6 in script.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`searchPeople` isn't dependent on any Angular setup, so it runs pretty much right away. Your controller constructor depends on all manner of time-consuming angular setup (module instantiation, dependency injection, ...) and only fires once those tasks are complete.

The code you write only sets up that controller function. It's Angular behind the scenes that actually invokes it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in the index.html, the controller is called before searchPeople() and shouldn't controller logic be printed first even if it is time-consuming?

Is there any way Line 12 executes after Line 6?

Comment: Nope. Don't get too hung up on the order of the lines. Line 6 doesn't call the controller function. It registers it with angular. It only gets called when angular is ready to call it. And while angular is getting ready to call it, the execution of `script.js` continues, eventually reaching the invocation of `searchPeople` on line 12.